# How to delete special cells?

Tags: office-scripts

This was my previous VBA code.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
Columns("S:S").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

I am rewriting with office scripts but am having a hard time getting this accomplished. Any ideas on how to remove all rows from column S that are blank?

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

```
  function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook){

  //get the used range in the worksheet (if you don't know the range that you need to look at) 
  let usedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getUsedRange();

  //get the row count of the used range
  let lastRow = usedRange.getRowCount();

  //set the range to start from cell A1 so if there are any blank rows above the used range, they will be removed too. The 19 is to include column S
  usedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRangeByIndexes(0,0, (usedRange.getRowIndex()+ lastRow), 19)

  //get the values of the range
  let values = usedRange.getValues();

  //get the row count of the range
  let rowCount = usedRange.getRowCount();

  //for every row starting at the last row, check if the cell in column 'S' is empty. If it is, then delete the entire row. 
  for (let i = rowCount-1; i>=0; i--){
    if ( values[i][18] == ""){
 usedRange.getCell(i,18).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Range getCell: The request payload size has exceeded the limit. 

The file itself is under 2MB with 275,000 cells in the table.

Comment: @BillR How many rows and columns do you have?

Comment: 33 columns, 10 - 15k rows.

Comment: Deleting the rows to under 5K still generates that same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
//My code if it helps?
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

// Get team_danny
let team_danny = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

// Create a table with the used cells.
let usedRange = team_danny.getUsedRange();
let newTable = workbook.addTable(usedRange, true);

// Find Last row
const lRow = getLastRow(workbook.getWorksheet("team_danny"), "B");

function getLastRow(sheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet, column: string): number {
let lastRange = team_danny.getUsedRange()?.getIntersection(`${column}:${column}`)?.
getLastCell() ?? team_danny.getRange(`${column}1`);
if (lastRange.getRowIndex() > 0 && lastRange.getValue() === "") {
lastRange = lastRange.getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up);
}
return lastRange.getRowIndex() + 1;
}

// Change Date Format
team_danny.getRange("S:S").setNumberFormatLocal("m/d/yyyy");

// Deletes 0 
team_danny.getRange("T:T").replaceAll("0", "", { completeMatch: true, matchCase: true });

// Deletes 0 
team_danny.getRange("V:V").replaceAll("0", "", { completeMatch: true, matchCase: true });

// Get Audit Date 
team_danny.getRange("S2").setFormulaLocal_
("=xlookup(O2,'Report'!E:E,'Report'!J:J,\"\")");

// Get 
team_danny.getRange("T2").setFormulaLocal("=xlookup(O2,'Report'!E:E,'Report'!H:H,\"\")");

// Get 
team_danny.getRange("V2").setFormulaLocal("=xlookup(O2,'Report'!E:E,'Report'!I:I,\"\")");

// Formulas written as values
team_danny.getRange("S2").copyFrom(team_danny.getRange(`S2:V${lRow}`), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values,
false, false);

let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");

// Apply checked items filter on table table1 column ReadCollectionDate
table1.getColumnByName("ReadCollectionDate").getFilter().applyValuesFilter([""]);

//get the used range in the worksheet (if you don't know the range that you need to look at) 
let usedRange2 = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getUsedRange();

//get the row count of the used range
let lastRow = usedRange2.getRowCount();

//set the range to start from cell A1 so if there are any blank rows above the used range, they will be removed too. The 19 is to include column S
usedRange2 = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, (usedRange2.getRowIndex() + lastRow), 19)

//get the values of the range
let values = usedRange2.getValues();

//get the row count of the range
let rowCount = usedRange2.getRowCount();

//for every row starting at the last row, check if the cell in column 'S' is empty. If it is, then delete the entire row. 
for (let i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
if (values[i][18] == "") {
usedRange2.getCell(i, 18).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the following code:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
    {
      let sh: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
      let tbl: ExcelScript.Table = sh.getTable("Table1");
      let rowCount: number = tbl.getRowCount();
      tbl.convertToRange();
      let ra: ExcelScript.RangeAreas = sh.getRange("S1:S" + rowCount).getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.blanks);
      let addresses: string[] = ra.getAreas().map(cell=>cell.getAddress());
    
      addresses.reverse().forEach(address=>{
        sh.getRange(address).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
      });
    }
```

If special cells doesn't have the option you need, you can also delete based on the cell value using nested for loops:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    
      let sheetName: string = "Sheet3";
      let tableName: string = "Table2";
      let columnName: string = "Col19";
    
      let sh: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheetName);
      let tbl: ExcelScript.Table = workbook.getTable(tableName);
      let tableColumn: ExcelScript.TableColumn = tbl.getColumn(columnName);
      let tableColumnRange: ExcelScript.Range = tableColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
      let tableColumnValues: (String|Number|Boolean)[][] = tableColumnRange.getValues();
      let rowCount: number = tableColumnRange.getRowCount();
      let colCount: number = tableColumnRange.getColumnCount();

      for (let i = rowCount-1; i>=0; i--){
          if (tableColumnValues[i][0] ==""){
            tbl.deleteRowsAt(i);
        }
      }

      tbl.convertToRange();
    }
```

This code goes through the values in the range of column S and iterates through it backwards from the last row to the first. It deletes the entire row where the value in column S for that row is blank.

One change from your VBA code is that I don't convert the table to a range until after I've deleted the rows. I do this so that I can take advantage of table methods like getTableColumn() and getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal(). I don't think it should make a difference however.

Comment: I am a little over my head. I am trying. I added it in and get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal')"

Comment: @BillR You have to update the sheetName, tableName, and columnName variables with the values for your table. Once you do that the code should work.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I worked through that and now the last line hangs "Table deleteRowsAt: Timeout"

Comment: @BillR I'm not sure why you're getting that error. I created a table with the number of columns (33) and the maximum number of rows you specified (15k) and the code worked fine for me. I'm wondering if the timeout is related to your script as a whole rather than the snippet of code I posted above.

Comment: I will be looking into that, thank you for all the help!